# T-SQL prepare dynamic COALESCE

Tags: sql-server, coalesce

As attached in screenshot, there are two tables.

1. **Configuration**:

[image]

2. **Detail**

Using `Configuration` and `Detail` table I would like to populate `IdentificationType` and `IDerivedIdentification` column in the `Detail` table.

Following logic should be used, while deriving above columns

1. `Configuration` table has order of preference, which user can change dynamically (i.e. if country is `Austria` then ID preference should be LEI then TIN (in case LEI is blanks) then CONCAT (if both blank then some other logic)
2. In case of contract ID = 3, country is BG, so LEI should be checked first, since its NULL, CCPT = 456 will be picked.

I could have used `COALESCE` and `CASE` statement, in case hardcoding is allowed.

Can you please suggest any alternation approach please ?

Regards

Digant

Comment: What is your attempt?

Comment: I am still unsure about approach (dynamic Sql or something else) rather than solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this is some horrendous data dump and you are trying to clean it up here is some SQL to throw at it. :)  Firstly, I was able to capture your image text via Adobe Acrobat > Excel.

(I also built the schema for you at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8f404/12)

Firstly, the correct thing to do is fix the glaring problem and that's the table structure. Assuming you can't here's a solution.

So, here it is and what it does is unpivots the columns LEI, NIND, CCPT and TIN from the detail table and also as well as FirstPref, SecondPref, ThirdPref from the Configuration table. Basically, doing this helps to normalize the data although it's costing you major performance if there are no plans to fix the data structure or you cannot. After that you are simply joining the tables `Detail.ContactId` to `DerivedTypes.ContactId` then `DerivedPrefs.ISOCountryCode` to `Detail.CountrylSOCountryCode` and `DerivedTypes.ldentificationType = DerivedPrefs.ldentificationType` If you use an inner join rather than the left join you can remove the `RANK()` function but it will not show all ContactIds, only those that have a value in their LEI, NIND, CCPT or TIN columns. I think that's a better solution anyway because why would you want to see an error mixed in a report? Write a separate report for those with no values in those columns. Lastly, the `TOP (1) with ties` allows you to display one record per ContactId and allows for the record with the error to still display. Hope this helps.

```
CREATE TABLE Configuration
    (ISOCountryCode varchar(2), CountryName varchar(8), FirstPref varchar(6), SecondPref varchar(6), ThirdPref varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO Configuration
    (ISOCountryCode, CountryName, FirstPref, SecondPref, ThirdPref)
VALUES
    ('AT', 'Austria', 'LEI', 'TIN', 'CONCAT'),
    ('BE', 'Belgium', 'LEI', 'NIND', 'CONCAT'),
    ('BG', 'Bulgaria', 'LEI', 'CCPT', 'CONCAT'),
    ('CY', 'Cyprus', 'LEI', 'NIND', 'CONCAT')
;


CREATE TABLE Detail
    (ContactId int, FirstName varchar(1), LastName varchar(3), BirthDate varchar(4), CountrylSOCountryCode varchar(2), Nationality varchar(2), LEI varchar(9), NIND varchar(9), CCPT varchar(9), TIN varchar(9))
;

INSERT INTO Detail
    (ContactId, FirstName, LastName, BirthDate, CountrylSOCountryCode, Nationality, LEI, NIND, CCPT, TIN)
VALUES
    (1, 'A', 'DES', NULL, 'AT', 'AT', '123', '4345', NULL, NULL),
    (2, 'B', 'DEG', NULL, 'BE', 'BE', NULL, '890', NULL, NULL),
    (3, 'C', 'DEH', NULL, 'BG', 'BG', NULL, '123', '456', NULL),
    (4, 'D', 'DEi', NULL, 'BG', 'BG', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
;


SELECT TOP (1) with ties Detail.ContactId,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    BirthDate,
    CountrylSOCountryCode,
    Nationality, 
    LEI, 
    NIND, 
    CCPT, 
    TIN, 
    ISNULL(DerivedPrefs.ldentificationType, 'ERROR') ldentificationType,
    IDerivedIdentification,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Detail.ContactId ORDER BY 
                    CASE WHEN Pref = 'FirstPref' THEN 1
                    WHEN Pref = 'SecondPref' THEN 2
                    WHEN Pref = 'ThirdPref' THEN 3
                    ELSE 99 END) AS PrefRank

FROM 
    Detail
LEFT JOIN   
(
    SELECT 
        ContactId, 
        LEI, 
        NIND,
        CCPT,
        TIN
    FROM Detail 
) DetailUNPVT
UNPIVOT
    (IDerivedIdentification FOR ldentificationType IN
        (LEI, NIND, CCPT, TIN)
    )AS DerivedTypes
ON DerivedTypes.ContactId = Detail.ContactId

LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        ISOCountryCode, 
        CountryName, 
        FirstPref, 
        SecondPref, 
        ThirdPref
    FROM
        Configuration
) ConfigUNPIVOT
UNPIVOT
    (ldentificationType FOR Pref IN
        (FirstPref, SecondPref, ThirdPref)
    )AS DerivedPrefs
ON DerivedPrefs.ISOCountryCode = Detail.CountrylSOCountryCode
and DerivedTypes.ldentificationType = DerivedPrefs.ldentificationType


ORDER BY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Detail.ContactId ORDER BY 
                    CASE WHEN Pref = 'FirstPref' THEN 1
                    WHEN Pref = 'SecondPref' THEN 2
                    WHEN Pref = 'ThirdPref' THEN 3
                    ELSE 99 END)
```